# Getting field values from Fragment in onTabSelected

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

I am trying to set up *validation script* between `tabs` (users cant switch from one tab to another without required fields being filled). I am having trouble getting field values from the `fragments`/`Tabs` to the `onTabSelected` method of my `TabListener` class. As it is I can identify the index of the selected tab and was hoping to use that validate fields of previous tab

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;


public class MyTabListener implements ActionBar.TabListener{

private Fragment fragment;




public MyTabListener(Fragment fragment) {
    this.fragment = fragment;
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    if(tab.getPosition() == 0)
    {
        ft.replace(R.id.content, fragment);
    }
    else if(tab.getPosition() == 1)
    {
        ft.replace(R.id.content, fragment);
    }
    else if(tab.getPosition() == 2)
    {
        ft.replace(R.id.content, fragment);
    }
}


@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    ft.remove(fragment);
}


@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

}

}
```

Comment: Are you using only one fragment?

Comment: Multiple fragments called by a  productTab.setTabListener(new MyTabListener(productsFragmentTab));

Answer (score 0):

Inside your fragment put a function

```
public static boolean checkValidation() {

/*...check validation for all fields here,
return true if all fields are filled else return false....*/

    if(validated){
       return true;
    }else {
       return false;
    }
return false;
}
```

Then inside onTabSelected

```
     @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    if(tab.getPosition() == 0)
    {
        if(YourFragment.checkValidation() == true) {
        ft.replace(R.id.content, fragment);
        } else{
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if this works. Just try this and let me know if this works. :)